# Testing tool that supports testng

Tags: eclipse, testing, testng

Which eclipse version is good for testing with [Testng](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftestng.org%2F&rct=j&q=testng&ei=2u90TaSkOYH_8Ab1psTuDg&usg=AFQjCNElXerOIRFjP9jjj2R9IwFHdBHHfA&cad=rja)?

Comment: This question lacks information. Have you tried anything yourself? Do you have any idea what you actually want?

Comment: yes i have tried eclipse but installing Testng on that gives me errors that "That no repository found on the site"

Comment: Are you sure you have used the correct url, as explained [here](http://testng.org/doc/download.html)? Which Eclipse version have you tried?

Comment: http://beust.com/eclipse. http://beust.com/eclipse1.

Comment: You will have to give more details about how exactly you are trying to install the plug-in, and what Eclipse you are installing it on. Feel free to do this on the testng-users mailing-list.

Comment: Version: Eclipse Ganymede 3.4,local  Archive Testng:org.testng.eclipse_5.14.10.20110304_1036,Website:http://beust.com/eclipse. ,process:1.Goto Help -> Software updates(a window open) click on available software,click on add sites ,enter the site . ok

Comment: This question lacks information and doesn't show any research effort

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Eclipse plugin with 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6.  I've been using the update site http://beust.com/eclipse as recommended in the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 3.3 and below
Eclipse 3.4 and above
Please visit the following URL:
http://testng.org/doc/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I am actively using InteliJ Idea to develop tests with TestNG.

1. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/